# need to write java program to fetch specific text

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee

so i dont have any idea how do i write such program ..please help...

so i want to write a program in java which reads the text between two strings

like i the full text is

```
             <name> XYZ </name>
```

so here i want to read the XYZ which can be anything i need the code so that it matches

```
        <name> ---- </name> and fetch the string in between them
```

and save it to a string..

please help me on this ..i dont know where to start..

i think i need to use regular expresion that matches the pattern

```
            <name>  </name>
```

but dont know how to do that....please suggest.........

Comment: why not try any XML parser?.. Jdom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.regex.*;

final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<name>(.+?)</name>");
final Matcher m = p.matcher("<name>any string you want to retrieve</name>");
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

then you can assign your matcher result to a String for further processing.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
 at org.read.Read.main(Read.java:16)

Comment: do i need to add something or is it the complete code...help !!

Comment: just fixed the tag property and the required import

Comment: @roanjain Mandatory link regarding this approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1393766